# If-else tree optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, code-generation, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to find a nice solution for following problem:

My input is a set of boolean variables `b0` to `bn` and 
a set of `if` statements calling some function in case the expression (conjunction of my boolean vars) is true.

For example:

```cpp
void test(bool b0, bool b1, bool b2, bool b3, bool b4) {
   if(b0&&b1) { action1(); }
   if(b0&&b1&&b3) { action2(); }
   if(b0&&b1&&b4) { action2(); }
   if(b0&&b2) { action3(); }
}
```

Obviously this code could be optimized in order to minimize the number of comparisons.

For instance:

```cpp
void test(bool b0, bool b1, bool b2, bool b3, bool b4) {
   if(b0) {
      if(b1) {
         action1();
         if(b3) { action2(); }
         if(b4) { action2(); }
      }
      if(b2) { action3(); }
   }
}
```

Is there an algorithm that solves/optimizes this problem (maybe even in an optimal way)?
It's obvious that it can be represented as a graph, table, etc. but somehow I still couldn't find a smart solution.

**Update:** I think I did not explain the problem well enough. Think about the problem as a truth table with multiple outputs. The inputs are the boolean variables and the outputs are the actions. So it is not just something that can be solved with KV map or Quine–McCluskey algorithm. Guess it is more complicated.

The table for the example above would be (I left out the "no output" cases):

```
b0| b1| b2| b3| b4 || action1 | action2 | action3  
1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0  || 1       | 0       | 0
1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0  || 1       | 1       | 0
1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1  || 1       | 1       | 0
1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0  || 0       | 0       | 1
```

Comment: Have you examined the generated assembly to deduce "*this code could be optimized in order to minimize the number of comparisons*"? I don't notice a vast difference between your two versions on https://godbolt.org/z/iEh9FE

Comment: I believe they mean to return actions instead of just running them and continue.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thanks for the comment. I guess gcc, clang, etc. are already doing a good job in optimizing such code. It is more an algorithmic question on how the number of comparisons could be minimized.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay It is not about returning something or not. I'm interested in minimizing the number of comparisons.

Comment: I mean does your code only perform one of the actions or it might perform a few of them. in the latter case I don't think your code even reduces the number of comparisions.

Comment: I'm not saying your question is without merit, but the point I was trying to make is that with an optimizing compiler it's almost impossible to know from source code how many comparisons are actually being made. Your metric for optimization here (number of comparisons) is poorly defined in such circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Don't optimise prematurely.

If you are thinking about such kind of optimizations you have to measure first. Make sure that this function is your hotspot in the production code. Thus,

- Turn on the highest optimisation level (-O3)
- Use a proper tool to locate hotspots, such as perf or Intel's vTune

Then if you find that this is your hotspot. Change it and measure again. You will be surprised in a lot of cases. It is quite possible, that the compiler will do this optimisation job for you.

Nevertheless, I think that the second version of your code can be read more fluently.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you need to deal with a bunch of boolean flags, merge them into a single uint32, which will allow you to test them fairly easily...

```
#include <cstdint>

enum Flags
{
  kB0 = 1 << 0,
  kB1 = 1 << 1,
  kB2 = 1 << 2,
  kB3 = 1 << 3,
  kB4 = 1 << 4,
  kB5 = 1 << 5,
};

inline bool testFlagsSet(uint32_t testFlags, uint32_t flags)
{
  return (testFlags & flags) == testFlags;
}

void test(uint32_t flags) {
  if(testFlagsSet(kB0 | kB1, flags)) { action1(); }
  if(testFlagsSet(kB0 | kB1 | kB3, flags)) { action2(); }
  if(testFlagsSet(kB0 | kB1 | kB4, flags)) { action3(); }
  if(testFlagsSet(kB0 | kB2, flags)) { action4(); }
}
```

You can ch:ek the difference between the approaches here:  https://godbolt.org/z/3P06fL

Also worth noting that of the original two methods you posted, the second one is better: https://godbolt.org/z/YTbYxh

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are asking. There are optimizing tools available to help to transform such code. But basically, it is not necessary.

And your new code is not better. It has even 5 if-statements. Performance wise, the compiler's optimizer will take care. It will detect the common subexpression and optimize that away.

This should also be basically done by the software developer / designer. A peer review will detect that code and fix the semantic problem.

You know of course that boolean expressions can be minimized via Quine&McCluskey or others. But I understand that this is not your question.

Static code analysis by Coverity / QAC / SonarCube can detect it, but will not fix it.  This needs to be done manually.

Or you need to evaluate source code optimizers like [PVS Studio](https://www.viva64.com/en/t/0084/)

Please check.

Comment: It's not really correct to call PVS Studio a code optimizer. It's a static analyzer with several warnings, related to possible optimizations.

Comment: Don't be so trusting of the compiler. https://godbolt.org/z/YTbYxh
Performance wise, the latter method presented by the OP produces better asm.

Comment: AT: GoverNator and at robthebloke: Yes and agreed. Thank you for the clarification. A good software design and algorithm will outperform any optimizer.